# opposed angles by a vertex

Tags: geometry

This question would seem rather silly because it is pretty elementary, but I got an argument with one pal that it made me feel dubious about the correct answer. In the following figures:
[image]

the question is: how many angles opposed by the vertex exist in both cases. According to the theory that I remember I have marked which angles are equal in the first picture and which angles would be equal in the second case. My answer would be two pairs opposed by the vertex in the first case with a total of 4 angles; and 4 pairs in the second case with a total of 8 angles. Would that be correct? Am I missing something? Thank you for your time and your help.

Comment: Is the question "how many angles" or "how many pair of angles"?

Comment: how many angles

Comment: @Lila: Your answer is correct, you are not missing anything.